# How do I yield pairwise combinations of a collection, ignoring order?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let's assume I have a collection (let's use a set):

```scala
scala> val x = Set(1, 2, 3)
x: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

I can get all pairwise combinations with the following code:

```scala
scala> for {
     | a <- x
     | b <- x
     | if a != b
     | } yield (a, b)
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(Int, Int)] = Set((3,1), (3,2), (1,3), (2,3), (1,2), (2,1))
```

The problem is that I only want to get all pairwise combinations where order is ignored (so the combination `(1, 2)` is equivalent to `(2, 1)`). So I'd like to return `Set((3, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2))`.

Do not assume that the elements of the collection will be integers. They may be any arbitrary type.

Any ideas?

Edit: Python's [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) performs the exact functionality I'm looking for. I just want an idiomatic way to do it in Scala :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Scala has a `combinations` method too, but it's only defined on `Seq`, not `Set`. So turn your set into a `Seq` first, and the following will give you an `Iterator[Seq[Int]]`:

```
x.toSeq.combinations(2)
```

If you really want tuples, add `map {case Seq(a,b) => (a,b)}` to the above.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind having a Set of Sets instead of a Set of tuples it is easy:

```
scala> val s3 = for {
     | a <- x
     | b <- x
     | if(a != b)
     | } yield ( Set(a,b))
s3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = Set(Set(1, 2), Set(1, 3), Set(2, 3))
```

Comment: And then you can map to tuples using `map { set => set.toList(0) -> set.toList(1) }` or something similar